# Mock multiple TypeORM repositories in NestJS

Tags: node.js, testing, dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm

I'm having trouble to mock multiple repositories from different modules in NestJS.

I'm using a `UsersRepository` from a `UsersModule` inside another module service (`NotesService`). The code is working fine, but I can't make the unit tests work.

I have the following error: `Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.`

## Minimal reproduction

```
// [users.module.ts]

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}


// [users.service.ts]

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private usersRepository: UsersRepository) {}
  ...
}


// [notes.module.ts]

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Note, User]),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [NotesController],
  providers: [NotesService],
})
export class NotesModule {
}

// [notes.service.ts]

@Injectable()
export class NotesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Note) private notesRepository: NotesRepository,
    @InjectRepository(User) private usersRepository: UsersRepository,
  ) {}
  ...
}
```

### Here is my unit test configuration:

```
// [notes.service.spec.ts]

beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [UsersModule],
      providers: [
        NotesService,
        { provide: getRepositoryToken(Note), useFactory: repositoryMockFactory },
        { provide: getRepositoryToken(User), useFactory: repositoryMockFactory },
      ],
    }).compile();

    notesService = module.get<NotesService>(NotesService);
    notesRepositoryMock = module.get(getRepositoryToken(Note));
  });
```

The problem is I can't make a proper mock of the `UsersRepository` that comes from another module.

I tried importing `TypeOrmModule` directly inside the test, and everything I could but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `import` the `UsersModule` if you are directly providing the `NotesService` and the mocks that it will depend on. The reason for the error is that Nest is trying to resolve `TypeormModule.forFeature([User])` from the `UsersModule`. Simply remove the import in the test and you should be golden.